# Função Javascript não é carregada com onload, mas é com onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Na página que estou desenvolvendo tenho esse código que dá início ao menu do site

```
<section id="yt_menu" class="block" style="visibility:hidden">
```

Estou usando *visibility:hidden* para deixar o menu oculto por padrão, e gostaria de exibi-lo apenas quando a página foi carregada, para isso mudei a tag *body* para *body onload="delayMenu();"* mas a função não é executada.

Segue função:

```
function delayMenu() {
    tempoDelay = setTimeout(showM, 2000); // 2 segundos após a página ser carregada
}
function showM() {
    document.getElementById("yt_menu").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Não sei se o problema está na função, pois se trocar *body onload* por *body onclick* funciona como deveria e o menu é exibido.

Também já tentei usar apenas *body* e deixar a função assim:

```
function delayMenu() {
    tempoDelay = setTimeout(showM, 2000); // 2 segundos após a página ser carregada
}
function showM() {
    document.getElementById("yt_menu").style.visibility = "visible";
}
window.onload = delayMenu;
```

Mas também não funcionou. Alguém já passou por isso? Saberia o que pode ser o problema?

O site está rodando em Joomla, e o primeiro exemplo funciona numa página "limpa", apenas não faz diferença quando aplico no site... o console do Google Chrome não mostra nenhum erro.

Comment: O teu código funciona como esperado.Ver [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvax4ovq/). Avalia melhor o restante do teu código e complementa a pergunta com mais informação se continuares a ter o problema.

Comment: @Zuul realmente, estou achando que é algum conflito com o restante do site, obrigado mesmo assim, estou a procurar a solução